# Android Studio: aapt.exe create too many processes and makes Android Studio very slow

Tags: performance, android-studio

This is my very first question on this website, so I apologize for any mistakes I do in this question.

Well to get to the point:
I currently have this problem with Android Studio, that it gets very slow while typing that means that it takes a while till I the characters appear when I type.(Note: Even after the Gradle is built)

So when I opened the Task-Manager I noticed that the the process aapt.exe 
(when I reseached it, it apearently is needed for compiling the code) 
has opened up to 20 Processes doing nothing except using my RAM Memeory.

When I shut them down I need to restart Android Studio because I wouldnt be able to start the emulator. (Error: Pipe is closing)

Since I havent find anything on the internet yet I ask you if somebody also has this issue.
Note that this issue accures on any project I make. I also dont really know why and when it occures, but I guess that it happenes when I try to start an emulation, or atleast this is the time I notice it.

Since I guess you will ask this:
System:

- Win10
- intel i7
- 8gb RAM
- 500gb
- Using Android Studio: 2.2.3
- JRE  1.8.0_76_release-b03 amd64
- Emulators used: Nexus 6 API 24 Nougat, Nexus 5 API 24 Nougat, Nexus 6P API 22 Lollipop

This problem is quite annoying while coding if you have to restart Android Studio all the time, which takes a lot of time.

*PS.: Hope I got the tags right.*

Comment: Any news? I have the same problem...

Comment: I get this now too didn't before last update.

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Did you get any solution for it ?

Comment: No sorry this issue remains....

Comment: I also facing this issue. Anyone have any solution to resolve this issue? This issue is annoying me now. so please I request to **android studio experts** give us any solution to resolve this hanging issue.

Answer (score 0):

Increase JVM heap size for both android studio and Gradle

**Android Studio**

Help > Edit Custom VMOptions > Put the following

```
-Xms1g
-Xmx4g
```

**Gradle**

```
android {
  ...
    dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }
```

Comment: what if vmoptions does not exists?

Answer (score 0):

In your `gradle.properties` file add these lines:

1. `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
2. `-Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

In your app level `build.gradle` file, add these lines:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```